# Make ForeignKey optional in Django Admin?

Tags: django, django-admin, django-forms

I have a custom django admin page, and I would like to make the two ForeignKey fields optional in the admin interface. I do not want to change the underlying model.

This is the model:

```
class IncorporationTicket(models.Model, AdminURL):
    ordered_by = models.ForeignKey('Organisation', # organisation which ordered this
                                   null = True,
                                   blank = False, # i.e. can only be null as a result of delete
                                   on_delete = models.SET_NULL)
    ordered_by_individual = models.ForeignKey('Individual', # individual at organisation which ordered this
                                               null = True,
                                               blank = False, # i.e. can only be null as a result of delete
                                               on_delete = models.SET_NULL)
```

(AdminURL is a mixin which provides get_absolute_url)

This is the ModelAdmin:

```
class TicketAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    readonly_fields = ('ordered', 'charge', 'amount_paid', 'submitted_on')

    formfield_overrides = {
        models.ForeignKey: {'required': False},
        }


    def formfield_for_foreignkey(self, db_field, request, **kwargs):
        pk = resolve(request.path).args[0] # the request url should only have one arg, the pk
        instance = self.get_object(request, pk) 
        user = request.user
        kwargs['required'] = False # will be passed to every field

        if db_field.name == "ordered_by_individual":
            # queryset should be a union of (a) individual already set on object (b) individual for current user
            ## None option is provided by admin interface - just need to let field be optional.
            if instance.ordered_by_individual:
                kwargs["queryset"] = (
                    Individual.objects.filter(pk = instance.ordered_by_individual.pk) |
                    user.individual_set.all())
            else: kwargs["queryset"] = user.individual_set.all()
        elif db_field.name == "ordered_by":
            # queryset should be a union of (a) organisation already set (b) any organisations for which user is authorised

           try:
               individual = user.individual_set.all()[0]
               all_orgs = Organisation.all_organisations_for_which_individual_authorised_to_incorporate(individual)
           except:
               all_orgs = Organisation.objects.none()
           if instance.ordered_by:
               kwargs["queryset"] = (
                   Organisation.objects.filter(pk = instance.ordered_by.pk) |
                   all_orgs)
           else: kwargs["queryset"] = all_orgs

        return super(type(self), self).formfield_for_foreignkey(db_field, request, **kwargs)
```

As you can see, I have tried to use both `formfield_overrides`, and `formfield_for_foreignkey` to set `required = False` on the FormField, but it is not having the required effect: **when attempting to save through the admin interface without setting (that is, leaving the field in its original blank state), the admin interface shows the error 'This field is required.'**

So, my question is: **how does one prevent the underlying form from requiring certain fields, while still also setting the choices in `formfield_for_foreignkey`?**

Answer (score 5, accepted):

While I'm not sure why `kwargs['required']` wouldn't work, you could always override the admin form with your own form. It hasn't failed me with magical django admin behavior so it's a pretty good bet.

```
class MyForm(forms.ModelForm):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(MyForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['my_fk_field'].required = False

    class Meta:
         model = MyModel

class MyAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    form = MyForm
```

This would still allow you to modify the `QuerySet` via the `formfield_for_foo` methods.

Comment: @Marcin, no it doesn't? That's the specific purpose of `formfield_for_foreignkey`, to override the form.

Comment: Actual testing shows that the queryset set in `formfield_for_foreignkey` is overridden by the default settings in a custom form.

Comment: @Marcin it's no longer a foreign key so we'd need a different hook. Alternatively how about the above? Set the field required attribute in the overriden form, and let django keep associating the field with `models.ForeignKey` so the admin lets you use the `formfield_for_foreignkey` hook

Answer (score 2):

... almost 9 years later, in Django v3.1.2 ...
`blank=True` works fine for me:

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

owner = models.ForeignKey(User, 
                          related_name="notes",
                          on_delete=models.CASCADE, 
                          null=True, 
                          blank=True)
```

(the solution has been taken from [here](https://djangobook-cn.readthedocs.io/en/latest/chapter06.html))