# What must I do to change a Django ForeignKey that originally was required to make it optional now?

Tags: django, django-models, django-admin

I have a data model with many ForeignKey fields.  From the original design, some are optional (via `blank=True, null=True`) while others are required (by relying on the defaults of `blank=False, null=False`).

Now, several years later, I wish to change a few of these to be optional.  I add `blank=True, null=True` to those fields on the data model, run `manage makemigrations` and `manage migrate`, yet the admin page behaves exactly as before: those that were once required are still required.

EDIT:
I've since learnt that I can override the AdminForm's `__init__` like below to resolve the problem.  I'd tried this earlier based on [Make ForeignKey optional in Django Admin?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8682156/make-foreignkey-optional-in-django-admin) but that didn't work for me; now it does so I must have goofed in my testing.  I am still very curious why this override is necessary though for FKs that weren't optional since their inception.

```
def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
    super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
    self.fields['SOME_FIELD_NAME'].required = False
```

EDIT #2:
Being suspicious that my troubles might stem from a FK on a model that is a base class for two subclasses, I thought I ought experiment with a simpler FK and guess what? I didn't have the problems there.  So to make things a bit more concrete for the reader here, I've implemented a Django interface to iptables and thus have the following data models relevant here:

```
class Protocol(models.Model):
    """
    A IP transmission protocol.
    """
    # details unimportant


class NetworkLocation(models.Model):
    """
    An abstract network location: a host or subnet.
    """
    # details unimportant


class Host(NetworkLocation):
    """
    A host name or its IP address.
    """
    # details unimportant


class Subnet(NetworkLocation):
    """
    A network IP address with /mask.
    """
    # details unimportant


class Rule(models.Model):
    """
    An iptables rule.
    """
    # only pertinent details shown here
    protocol = models.ForeignKey(Protocol, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    src = models.ForeignKey(
        NetworkLocation, verbose_name='source',
        blank=True, null=True, related_name='+', on_delete=models.CASCADE,
    )
    dst = models.ForeignKey(
        NetworkLocation, verbose_name='destination',
        blank=True, null=True, related_name='+', on_delete=models.CASCADE,
    )
```

So based on the above, my problems were with `Rule`.  As incepted, `protocol`,
`src` and `dst` were all required.  Now I wanted to make `src` and `dst`
optional and hence this SO question.  I just learned that I could make
`protocol` optional through the mere addition of `blank=True, null=True` but
for `src` and `dst` it seems necessary to have the `__init__` of my
`RuleAdminForm` extended as shown further above.  Why is that necessary for
`src` and `dst` but not `protocol`?

Comment: How do you know they're still required? What is the behavior?

Comment: The Admin form states "Please correct the errors below." and "This field is required." right after I press Save.