# Allow empty foreign key selection in admin forms

Tags: python, django, django-forms, django-admin

I created a model(AnalysisFieldTemplate) with a foreign key to AnalysisFieldRule.
What i want is to have the possibility to leave the field display_analysis_field_rule blank and save my admin form.

```
class AnalysisFieldRule(models.Model):
    action_kind: str = models.CharField(
        choices=ActionKind.choices,
        default=ActionKind.DISPLAY,
        max_length=text_choices_max_length(ActionKind),
        verbose_name=_("action kind"),
    )
    formula: str = formula_field()
    name: str = models.CharField(max_length=MAX_NAME_LENGTH, verbose_name=_("name"))

    def __str__(self):
        return f"{self.name}: {ActionKind(self.action_kind).label}"

    class Meta:
        constraints = [
            UniqueConstraint(fields=("action_kind", "name"), name="%(app_label)s_%(class)s_is_unique"),
        ]
        ordering = ["name", "action_kind"]
        verbose_name = _("analysis field rule")
        verbose_name_plural = _("analysis field rules")

class AnalysisFieldTemplate(models.Model):
    display_analysis_field_rule: AnalysisFieldRule = models.ForeignKey(
        AnalysisFieldRule,
        blank=True,
        limit_choices_to={"action_kind": ActionKind.DISPLAY},
        null=True,
        on_delete=models.PROTECT,
        related_name="display_analysis_field_templates",
        verbose_name=_("display rule"),
    )
```

Now here is the problem. If i try to save my admin form without choosing one a value for display_analysis_field_rule it will result in an Validationerror.
It seems that the standard empty value for a foreign key "------" is not a valid choice.

[image]

```
@admin.register(AnalysisFormTemplate)
class AnalysisFieldTemplateAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    fieldsets = (
        (
            None,
            {
                "fields": (
                    "name",
                    "name_for_formula",
                    "ordering",
                    "required",
                    "kind",
                    "display_analysis_field_rule",
                    "highlight_analysis_field_rule",
                )
            },
        ),
        (
            _("Text options"),
            {"fields": ("max_length",)},
        ),
        (
            _("Integer options"),
            {"fields": ("min_integer_value", "max_integer_value")},
        ),
        (_("Amount of money options"), {"fields": ("min_amount_of_money", "max_amount_of_money")}),
    )
```

I debugged a little deeper and found that the "to_python" compares the choosen value with pythons standard "empty_values" but of course it contains not the "------" and it will handle it as a normal id which results in an Validation error.

My question is how can i make it possible to save my form without choosing a value for my foreign key? Do i have to override the "to_python" function? What would be a best practice here?

I appreciate all the help :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution which worked for me was to create a custom form and override the empy_values for each of my foreing keys with its empty_label.

```
from django.core.validators import EMPTY_VALUES  # NOQA

def empty_values_list_for_foreign_key(empty_label:str):
    empty_values_list = list(EMPTY_VALUES)
    empty_values_list.append(empty_label)
    return empty_values_list


class AnalysisFieldTemplateAdminForm(forms.ModelForm):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields["display_analysis_field_rule"].empty_values = empty_values_list_for_foreign_key(self.fields["display_analysis_field_rule"].empty_label)
        self.fields["highlight_analysis_field_rule"].empty_values = empty_values_list_for_foreign_key(self.fields["highlight_analysis_field_rule"].empty_label)


@admin.register(AnalysisFieldTemplate)
class AnalysisFieldTemplateAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    form = AnalysisFieldTemplateAdminForm
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to create custom modelform for your use case and make the particular field with required=False

```
class MyForm(forms.ModelForm):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(MyForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['display_analysis_field_rule'].required = False
        self.fields['display_analysis_field_rule'].empty_label = None

    class Meta:
         model = MyModel  # Put your model name here
         

@admin.register(AnalysisFormTemplate)
class AnalysisFieldTemplateAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    form = MyForm
# .... your stuff
```

Comment: This didn't work, because my fields "required" is already set to "False". But what i can do is change my empty_label for the field to "" which will than work. But it seems not to be the best possible way to handle it.

Comment: Where have you set required=False in your code ?

Comment: After debuggin, it was already set to false. I didn't set it myself, but seems like it will be set automatically if i my foreign key hast the values null=True und blank=True.

Comment: Which django version you are using ?

Comment: I am using django version 3.2.13

Comment: But can you try with the approach I have suggested and let me know if it works for you ?

Comment: Already tried it. Didn't work :/

Comment: I have included this field only for example `self.fields['display_analysis_field_rule'].required = False` there may be other fields as well have you marked all of them with required=False'

Comment: Also check this thread https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8682156/make-foreignkey-optional-in-django-admin

Comment: Yeah there are other, but the error message for this specific field didn't vanish after adding it. And all the others are also already set to "requiered = False"

Comment: Also my error message is not that my field is required but rather that the selected choice is not a valid one.

Comment: Can you check now with the updated part I have updated the empty_label

Comment: So i tried it with your updated part but it also didn't work. But i manage to bring it to work. Had to add the empty_label to the empty_values. I will edit my question.

Comment: Anyway you can upvote it if you find it helpful /:

Comment: I would like to, but currently i have not enough rep points to do so :D.